# Swift 3 UIImageView Order

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have a UIImageView in my Storyboard.  In my code I add additional UIImageViews and want them to appear behind the one that already exists in the Storyboard.  My code is:

```
imageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName+".jpg")
imageView?.frame.size = CGSize(width: w, height: h)
imageView?.layer.opacity = 0
imageView?.center = self.moveButtons[idx].center
self.view.addSubview(imageView!)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.5, animations: {
    imageView?.frame.origin.x += (imageView?.frame.size.width)!/2
    imageView?.layer.opacity=1
    self.playerImages[self.currentPlayer].bringSubview(toFront: self.view)
})
```

I thought that self.playerImages[self.currentPlayer].bringSubview(toFront: self.view) would do the trick but it didn't.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bring the imageView to the front and not self.view.

```
self.playerImages[self.currentPlayer].bringSubview(toFront: imageView!)
```

Comment: Duh!  Sometimes I just need to slap myself in the forehead! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the image view is a subview of the controller's main view you need to tell **that** view to be bring the image view to the front:

```
let playerImage = self.playerImages[self.currentPlayer]
self.view.bringSubview(toFront: playerImage)
```